# Research vs Review paper

Tags: paper-submission, publishability, review-articles

Objectively, is it more difficult to get published a research or a review paper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no data available of rejection rates enriched with information about the paper type. Therefore, you can't tell objectively.